# Comparing two vectors MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to get the error rate of 2 vectors?

like

```
                # incorrect numbers           6
error rate  = ______________________    =    ____ 
               # total numbers(size)          15
```

here are `15` numbers, `9` are correct
`x` is the true answer (the reference), and `y` is vector with answers
I would like to compare them and get error rate:

```
x= [1 ,1,1, 1,1, 1,1,1,1,1, 1,-1,-1,-1,-1] 
y= [-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1, 1,-1, 1,-1]
```

- Also is it corret what I am doing?
  Ok I was wrong about the formula I updated it.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried substracting them, but like `x-y`, and if the result is 0 they are equal, but do not how to code in MATLAB  `size(x-y < 0);` but don't get correct answer

Comment: Ok, so, we need another substractring right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the *error* rate, then you want the number of *incorrect* values divided by the total number of values. You can do this using the [relational operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/relationaloperators.html) `~=` and the function [MEAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html):

```
errorRate = mean(x ~= y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version that works:

```
length(find(x~=y))/length(y)
```